# Why does JsonResult resolve to a different type?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer

My MVC 3 controller returns a JsonResult containing a List, which resolves to a javascript array on the client.  I can see this by performing a quickwatch on the javascript object using the IE developer tools.

variableName    [variableValue] Object, (Array)

Now, I run this exact same web site from a different PC, and the result resolves simply as an Object, not an array.

variableName    [variableValue] Object

These are both IE 9, just on two different machines.  Does anyone know why this is and how I can control it so that the javascript rendering is always and Array?  Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide some more context, why this causing you problems? Can you add maybe some code: the controller action, and what do you try to do with the result in js?

Answer (score 0):

I overlooked the fact that the browser that does not work is actually IE8, where the one that does work is IE9.  Discrepency explained.